# Count occurences of specific values in a data frame, where all possible values are defined by a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have two categories **A** and **B** that can take on **5 different states** (values, names or categories) defined by the list **abcde**. Counting the occurence of each state and storing it in a data frame is fairly easy. However, I would also like the resulting data frame to include zeros for the possible values that have not occured in Category **A** or **B**.

First, here's a dataframe that matches the description:

In[1]:

```
import pandas as pd
possibleValues = list('abcde')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Category A':list('abbc'), 'Category B':list('abcc')})
print(df)
```

Out[1]:

```
        Category A      Category B
0       a               a
1       b               b
2       b               c
3       c               c
```

I've tried different approaches with `df.groupby(...).size()` and `.count()` , combined with the list of possible values and the names of the categories in a list, but with no success.

Here's the desired output:

```
        Category A      Category B
a       1               1
b       2               1
c       1               2
d       0               0
e       0               0
```

To go one step further, I'd also like to include a column with the totals for each possible state across all categories:

```
        Category A      Category B      Total
a       1               1               2
b       2               1               3
c       1               2               3
d       0               0               0
e       0               0               0
```

SO has got many related questions and answers, but to my knowledge none that suggest a solution to this particular problem. Thank you for any suggestions!

P.S

I'd like to make the solution adjustable to the number of categories, possible values and number of rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) + [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) + [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) + [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
cols = ['Category A','Category B']
df1 = df[cols].apply(pd.value_counts).reindex(possibleValues, fill_value=0)
df1['total'] = df1.sum(axis=1)
print (df1)
   Category A  Category B  total
a           1           1      2
b           2           1      3
c           1           2      3
d           0           0      0
e           0           0      0
```

Another solution is convert columns to [categorical](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) and then `0` values are added without `reindex`:

```
cols = ['Category A','Category B']
df1 = df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.Series.value_counts(x.astype('category', 
                                                                categories=possibleValues)))
df1['total'] = df1.sum(axis=1)
print (df1)
   Category A  Category B  total
a           1           1      2
b           2           1      3
c           1           2      3
d           0           0      0
e           0           0      0
```