# Python pandas, aggregate values by date in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame that contains thousands of dates and IDs as follows:

```
2/1/18  123
2/1/18  123
2/1/18  456
2/1/18  789
```

I also have a short list of only a few IDs such as:

```
 ids=['123','456','909']
```

I need to loop through the list and get a count of each value in the list by date. So the result should look like;

```
2/1/18 123 2
       456 1
       909 0
```

I can do a groupby easy enough on the data frame but that will return all ids and I only need the values from the id list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count occurences of specific values in a data frame, where all possible values are defined by a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44261567/count-occurences-of-specific-values-in-a-data-frame-where-all-possible-values-a)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['2/1/18', 123],
                  ['2/1/18', 123],
                  ['2/1/18', 456],
                  ['2/1/18', 789]],
                  columns=['Date', 'ID'])

ids = ['123','456','909']

df['count'] = 1
results = df[df['ID'].isin(ids)].groupby(['Date', 'ID']).count()
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using `reindex` here

```
df.loc[df.Id.isin(ids)].groupby('Date').Id.value_counts().reindex(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.Date.unique(),ids]),fill_value=0)
Out[1116]: 
2/1/18  123    2
        456    1
        909    0
Name: Id, dtype: int64
```